# Angular v4 and Swiper: Multiple Instances of Swiper on Same page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, swiper.js

I'm using Angular v.4 and Swiper.js and I have a problem with multiple instance of swiper. Above the use case:
In my view, I have a multiple instances of a same component (slider-detail):

```
<section class="tv-container">

  <section *ngIf="creditsTv.cast.length > 0">
    <slider-detail [items]="creditsTv.cast" [title]="'Top Billed Cast'" [url]="'/main/tv/wall/popular'"></slider-detail>
  </section>

  <section>
    <slider-detail [items]="similarTv.results" [title]="'Similar'" [url]="'/main/tv/wall/popular'"></slider-detail>
  </section>

  <section *ngIf="recommendationsTv.results.length > 0">
    <slider-detail [items]="recommendationsTv.results" [title]="'Recommendations'" [url]="'/main/tv/wall/popular'"></slider-detail>
  </section>

</section>
```

and this is my **slider-detail.component.html** component:

```
<section class="list-section">
  <h1 class="title-section">
    {{title}}
  </h1>
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let item of items">
          <slide-credit [item]="item"></slide-credit>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and this is my **slider-detail.component.ts** component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'slider-detail',
  templateUrl: './slider-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider-detail.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SliderDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() items: any;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() url: string;

  private _swiper: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Initialize Swiper
    this._swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      initialSlide: 0,
      direction: "horizontal",
      slidesPerView: "auto",
      slidesPerGroup: 2,
      nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
      slidesOffsetBefore: 0,
      slidesOffsetAfter: 0,
      observer: true,
      observeParents: true
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // this._swiper.update(true);
    this._swiper.destroy();
  }

}
```

Now, when change the route, I want to destroy (ngOnDestroy()) the this._swiper but I obtain this error:

> this._swiper.destroy is not a function

If I print the this._swiper before to this._swiper.destroy(), I have an array of swiper instance.
So to destroy instance I must do this._swiper[index].destroy() but I haven't the index.

How can i fix it? Do you have another solutions?
Can I wrap the instance to class and not globally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Prior to adding the new swiper object, get the length of the current swiper instances array. That should be your index.

```
let index: number = this._swiper.length - 1;
if (index < 0) {
    index = 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working. If I add your code and after print the index I obtain always index = 0.